# How can I change the Desktop background or the screensaver in Terminal only?

Tags: linux, gnome, opensuse, suse

I have a few images in a directory and I can only use the Terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`gconftool-2 -t str -s /desktop/gnome/background /where/is/your/image/linux_12.jpg`

Comment: For screensaver, I used $gconftool-2 --direct --config-schema xml:readwrite:/etc/gnconf.xml.mandatory --type boolean --set /apps/gnome-screensaver/lock_enabled true

I get the following error:
Error setting value: Can't overwrite existing read-only value: Value for '/apps/gnome-screensaver/lock_enabled' set in a read-only source at the fron of your configuration path

Any idea on how to solve this? chmod didn't work

Comment: @Wasi did you try with sudo? (I have to ask)

Comment: I did. Same error

Comment: @Wasi what permission does it have?? I mean more accurately, does it have sticky bit?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what version of GNOME you are using. Assuming you are using one of the later versions of GNOME, you can try this command to change the background:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///path/to/your/image.png
```

Change the path to the file and the wallpaper will be changed accordingly.

GNOME started migrating most of its settings from gconf to dconf and as such, the [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/480954/104400) will not work for newer versions of GNOME.

[(Source)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156713/change-desktop-background-from-terminal)